# Print the number of each set of duplicate strings and their indexes from a large list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to find duplicates strings in a list ~100,000 and count how many they are of each and the index they are located and print them. So far I came up with this:

```
 list_b = ['04/Sep/2016:00:00:03 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:04 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:05 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:06 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:06 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:08 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:08 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:08 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:11 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:15 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:19 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:20 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:23 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:25 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:26 -0400']

for i in list_b:
    if(i in list_b):
        print(i + " Amount of duplicates: " + amount of duplicates + " Index of duplicates: " + index of duplicate)
```

output should be like this:

```
"04/Sep/2016:00:00:06 -0400  Amount of duplicates:  2 Index of duplicates: 3,4"
"04/Sep/2016:00:00:08 -0400  Amount of duplicates:  3 Index of duplicates: 5,6,7"
```

Comment: What if you create a dictionary with key as the `timestamp` and value as the `count` of the number of times you encountered it? But then creating the dictionary would be a `O(n)` operation and printing would be a `O(n)` operation too which is approx `O(n)` anyways. If that's something you are okay with I will write some code.

Comment: Are you ok with using third party libs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_b = ['04/Sep/2016:00:00:03 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:04 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:05 -0400',
          '04/Sep/2016:00:00:06 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:06 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:08 -0400',
          '04/Sep/2016:00:00:08 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:08 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:11 -0400',
          '04/Sep/2016:00:00:15 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:19 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:20 -0400',
          '04/Sep/2016:00:00:23 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:25 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:26 -0400']

indices_dict = defaultdict(list)

for index, value in enumerate(list_b):
    indices_dict[value].append(index)

for value, index_list in indices_dict.items():
    num_duplicates = len(index_list)
    if num_duplicates > 1:
        print("%s Amount of duplicates: %s, Indices of duplicates: %s" %
              (value, num_duplicates, index_list))
```

Comment: I know those are not nested for loops but wouldn't this still be O(n^2) `if n == len(timestamps)` anyways?

Comment: @trendsetter37 no, why would you think that? The first loop runs through `n` items, the second loop runs through less, and at no other point are many items processed. Lookups and insertions into the dictionary are roughly O(1). I tested the code and it runs almost instantly.

Comment: Oops, yea you're right. The indices_dict is a collapsed version of list_b.

Comment: This is quick for my large list but it's seems to not work for python3, only Python 2. But it did the job!

Comment: @DanielPlasRivera what problem did you have with Python 3? I can't find any.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_b = ['04/Sep/2016:00:00:03 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:04 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:05 -0400',
          '04/Sep/2016:00:00:06 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:06 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:08 -0400',
          '04/Sep/2016:00:00:08 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:08 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:11 -0400',
          '04/Sep/2016:00:00:15 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:19 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:20 -0400',
          '04/Sep/2016:00:00:23 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:25 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:26 -0400']

duplicates = set()

for i in list_b:
    indices = [pos for pos, s in enumerate(list_b) if s == i]
    if len(indices) > 1:
        duplicates.add("%s Ammount of duplicates: %d Index of duplicates: %s" % (i, len(indices), indices))

for dup in duplicates:
    print(dup)
```

Comment: There's a lot of redundant work here. `for i in list_b: count = list_b.count(i)` is O(n^2), then the list comprehension adds more.

Comment: @AlexHall Fair enough. Updated.

Comment: `for i in list_b: indices = [...]` is still O(n^2).

Comment: @AlexHall You need to find all indices so it is O(n^2) anyway.

Comment: No, my answer is O(n). I'm testing your code with 90,000 elements by printing out the position within the loop every ten seconds and I get 461, 940, 1385... this will take forever.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```
mylist =  ["a", "a", "b", "c", "b"]

for index, item in enumerate(mylist):
    rep_time = mylist.count(item)
    print(item, " Amount of duplicates: ", rep_time, "| Index of duplicates: ", index)
```

tested on python 3 and it worked fine

Comment: It prints out true information, but not in the way OP wanted. For example it prints out `a  Amount of duplicates:  2` twice, once for each occurrence of `"a"`, and it prints out all the indices in order, one per line.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. OP gave some sample output, e.g. `04/Sep/2016:00:00:06 -0400  Amount of duplicates:  2 Index of duplicates: 3,4`. Note how it puts both indices (`3,4`) in one line. Your script does not output in that format.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_b = ['04/Sep/2016:00:00:03 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:04 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:05 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:06 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:06 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:08 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:08 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:08 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:11 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:15 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:19 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:20 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:23 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:25 -0400', '04/Sep/2016:00:00:26 -0400']
results={}
for i in range(len(list_b)):
    if list_b[i] not in results:
        results[list_b[i]]={'string':list_b[i],'count':list_b.count(list_b[i]),'index':[i]}
    else:
        results[list_b[i]]['index'].append(i)
for result in results:
    if len(results[result]['index'])>1:
        print results[result]['string'],'Amount of duplicates:',results[result]['count'],'Index of Duplicates:',",".join(map(str,results[result]['index']))
```

Output

```
04/Sep/2016:00:00:06 -0400 Amount of duplicates: 2 Index of Duplicates: 3,4
04/Sep/2016:00:00:08 -0400 Amount of duplicates: 3 Index of Duplicates: 5,6,7
```

Comment: This is O(n^2) when all the strings are unique, as it will do `list_b.count` (an O(n) operation) n times. To demonstrate, make `list_b = list(map(str, range(100000)))` then add `if i % 1000 == 0: print(i)` at the start of the loop: it prints quite slowly.